# php select records between 2 dates with formatted date column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, date

I need to select orders' records between 2 dates. the date format on the database is looks like :
January 1, 2020 -> using `%F %j, %Y` format.

my try to get the records is:

```
$from_date = 'January 1, 2020';
$to_date = 'January 5, 2020';

$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE order_date STR_TO_DATE(order_date, '%F %j, %Y') between STR_TO_DATE('$from_date', '%F %j, %Y') and STR_TO_DATE('$to_date', '%F %j, %Y') 
 GROUP 
    BY order_id
";
```

the result is `null`

also I tried to use `convert(order_date,'%F %j, %Y')` but not work and shows me the same result `null`

hope I explain the issue clearly.

Thanks

Comment: How is the date actually stored in the DB?  2020-01-01?

Comment: `... order_date STR_TO_DATE(order_date, '%F %j, %Y') between ...` -- that's wrong, there's two first operands to to `BETWEEN` where it only takes one. But you shouldn't do any manual date formatting and use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation anyway.

Comment: `WHERE order_date STR_TO_DATE` is nonsense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `'%F'` specifier in MySQL. You probably want `%M'` instead.

Also, `'%j'` should be `'%e'`: the latter gives you the number of a day in the month (from `1` to `31`), while the former is the number of a day in the year (from `1` to `365` - or `366` on leap years).

Your `where` clause should look like:

```
where str_to_date(order_date, '%M %e, %Y') 
    between str_to_date(:from_date, '%M %e, %Y') and str_to_date(:to_date, '%M %e, %Y')
```

Notes:

- Use prepared statements! Do not concatenate variables in the query string: this is both inefficient (the database needs to parse the statement everytime it is executed with different parameters) and unsafe (your code is opened to SQL injection)
- You should really consider using the proper datatype to store your data; storing dates as strings is inefficient (you need to convert the strings whenever you need to filter them) and unsafe (you cannot guarantee data integrity at the time when the data is stored in the table)
- `select *` and `group by` do not go along well together

Comment: +1 - and also if you use a function on the row data in WHERE MySQL MUST read each Row and convert it. So it a FULL TABLE SCAN and cant use any Index.